# How to avoid shimmering with rotated spriteBatch?

Tags: c#, xna

I am writing a camera module to my XNA project and I encountered a problem lately.

I allowed camera rotation to my module and I got a fabulous bug - every time I draw multiple sprites in the same position, spriteBatch once draws one in front, second time the second one in front, and what is even funnier, sometimes two sprites are shown, with different alphas.

I've made few experiments:

1. When I set `SpriteBatch` mode to `Deffered` it is all ok - but I want to have access to z-index.
2. When I draw a whole 500x500 tiles array (all the sprites loaded), it is all ok, but when I get like 50x50 square from the array (containing the whole desired screen content) it gets bugged.
3. Finally different states are always happening for the same angle.

I must add that I do translation myself - in order to get double precision. Here is the method for translations:

```
public void DrawSprite(Sprite toDraw)
{       
    // TODO: Think about converting constructor
    Vector2D drawingPostion;
    Vector2 drawingPos;
    drawingPostion = toDraw.Position - Position;
    drawingPos.X = (float) drawingPostion.X * GraphicsManager.Instance.UnitToPixels;
    drawingPos.Y = (float) drawingPostion.Y * GraphicsManager.Instance.UnitToPixels;
    spriteBatch.Draw(toDraw.Texture, drawingPos, toDraw.Source, toDraw.Color,
                    toDraw.Rotation, toDraw.Origin, toDraw.Scale, toDraw.Effects, toDraw.LayerDepth);
}
```

My ideas for the problem:

- Fix the bug somehow (if it's possible)
- Force XNA to sort first by z-index and then by drawing order.
- Apply some z-indexes everywhere, where overlapping can occur (don't like this)
- Abandon z-index (don't want that either)

Comment: Look into `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront);` and the `DrawOrder` property on `DrawableGameComponent`

Comment: I am actually not using `DrawableGameComponent`s, but I can use `LayerDepth` anyway.
Back to front is what I use right now and it seems that when there are two sprites of the same `LayerDepth`, the system gets broken for some angle rates. It doesn't care about the order in which I evoked `SpriteBatch.Draw()` method.
What is concerning me is that, when I draw all the loaded sprites it seems to work fine :/

Answer (score 1):

As *lukegravitt* suggested, you should use `SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack`:

> Sprites are sorted by depth in front-to-back order prior to drawing.
>   This procedure is recommended when drawing opaque sprites of varying
>   depths.

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx).

So you can easily set the z-index with the last parameter of `SpriteBatch.Draw`:

```
float layerDepth
```

> The depth of a layer. By default, 0 represents the front layer and 1
>   represents a back layer. Use SpriteSortMode if you want sprites to be
>   sorted during drawing.

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx).

Comment: Actually in my case I really ended up with FrontToBack (I use 1 as the front and 0 as the back). Combining your answer and mine I could finally get a solution.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally picked the option C), here is how it works in my code:

```
public void DrawSprite(Sprite toDraw)
        {
            // TODO: Think about converting constructor
            Vector2D drawingPostion;
            Vector2 drawingPos;
            drawingPostion = toDraw.Position - Position;
            drawingPos.X = (float) drawingPostion.X * GraphicsManager.Instance.UnitToPixels;
            drawingPos.Y = (float) drawingPostion.Y * GraphicsManager.Instance.UnitToPixels;

            // proceeding to new z-index
            zsortingValue += 0.000001f;

            spriteBatch.Draw(toDraw.Texture, drawingPos, toDraw.Source, toDraw.Color,
                toDraw.Rotation, toDraw.Origin, toDraw.Scale, toDraw.Effects, toDraw.LayerDepth + zsortingValue);
        }
```

where `zsortingValue` is zeroed whenever a frame begins. This way each sprite can have its own sorting value, which is being enhanced only.